# When is it $C(X)$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, von-neumann-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras, banach-spaces

Suppose that $\tilde{X}$ is a compact space. If $C(\tilde{X})$ is isometrically isomorphic to the second dual of a Banach space, does there exist a locally compact space $X$ such that $C(\tilde{X})=C_0(X)^{**}$?

P.S. Note that the converse is always true, namely if $X$ is a locally compact space, there is a compact space $\tilde{X}$ such that $C_0(X)^{**}=C(\tilde{X})$. The Banach space $C_0(X)^{**}$ turns into a Banach algebra with the first (second) Arens product. This is a non-trivial product on $C_0(X)^{**}$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that $C(X)$ can't be the dual of any Banach space by the Krein-Milman theorem...

Comment: I don't see why that's true. Here is an example. If $X$ is a locally compact space, then $C_0(X)^{**}$ is a unital commutative $C^*-$algebra and therefore it is in the form of $C(\tilde{X})$ for a compact space $\tilde{X}$. This ($C(\tilde{X})$) gives an example of a $C(X)$ that is a dual of a Banach space.

Comment: What is your proposed C*-algebra structure on $C(X)^{**}$?

Comment: Let's make things more concrete.  Consider the case $X = [0,1]$, and suppose $C(X)$ were the dual of a Banach space.  By Krein-Milman the unit ball of $C(X)$ would be the closed convex hull of its extreme points, but I claim the constant functions $1$ and $-1$ are the only extreme points.  Indeed, suppose $f$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$ with max value $1$, but suppose $f(x) < 1$ for some $x$.  Choose a bump function $g$ of very small height which is supported in a very small neighborhood of $x$, and observe that $f$ is the convex combination of $f + g$ and $f-g$.

Comment: @PaulSiegel just take an abelian von Neumann algebra. Diffuse would get you a dual space, atomic would get you a bidual space.

Comment: OK, so the examples of spaces $X$ that we're talking about are god-awful then...

Comment: A reference can be "Seever, G. L., Algebras of continuous functions on hyper-stonian spaces, Arch. Math. (Basel) 24 (1973), 648–660". Very briefly, if you have a Banach algebra then you can make its second dual into a Banach algebra using [Arens product](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Arens_multiplication). Now it can be shown that the second dual of a $C^*-$algebra is again a $C^*-$algebra with the Arens product. You can also show that in the case of $C(X)$, the Arens product on $C(X)^{**}$ is commutative (please, see the end of page 8 of the above paper).

Comment: Also, since $C_0(X)$ has an approximate identity, $C_0(X)^{**}$ must have a unit. So all these together implies that $C_0(X)^{**}$ is a unital commutative $C^*-$algebra.

Comment: If $K$ is a compact space and $C(K)$ is isomorphic to a second dual, then it is injective and, by a result of Haydon, it is isomorphic to $\ell_\infty(\Gamma)$ for some set $\Gamma$. Hence $C(K)$ is isomorphic to $c_0(\Gamma)^{**}$.

Comment: @M.González Thanks - I wasn't aware of Haydon's paper. Am I right in thinking that he only proves "isomorphic" and not "isometrically isomorphic"? Regardless, you should post your comment (perhaps with some added references) as an answer

Comment: @Yemon Choi: Yes. He only proves isomorphic. This is the reason I did not put it as an answer. I will put a more detailed version as an answer.

Comment: I like this formulation of your question better. Suppose $Y$ is  $\mathcal{L}_\infty$ $1+\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon >0$.  Is there a compact Hausdorff space $K$ s.t. $C(K)^*$ is isometrically isomorphic to $Y^*$?  Lacey showed that the answer is yes if $Y$ is separable. I have no idea what the answer is when the density character of $Y$ is uncountable.

Comment: Continuing:  Maharam's theorem gives a characterization of $L_1(\mu)$ spaces, but which ones of these are isometric to dual spaces?  The answer could be easy, but is unknown to me.

Answer (score 5):

Only a partial answer, but too long for comments.

This was question 3 considered at a BIRS meeting in 2012 — I wonder if your question is motivated by seeing it here or raised elsewhere by Dales or his collaborators?

In any case, according to the final report (see the sidebar) the answer is *yes* when $C(\widetilde{X})$ is assumed to be isometric to the bidual of a *separable* Banach space, by old results of H. E. Lacey:

H. E. Lacey. *A note concerning $A^{\ast} =L_1(\mu )$.* Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 29 (1971) 525—528.
[Link to paper.](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1971-029-03/S0002-9939-1971-0278040-7/)

If I understand Lacey's result correctly, it says that if $C(\widetilde{X})=A^{**}$ for $A$ a separable Banach space then $C(\widetilde{X})$ is the bidual of $c_0$ or of $C[0,1]$.

It appears that at the time that report was written, the general case was still open. Perhaps if Fred Dashiell is still on MathOverflow he might be able to inform us of any further progress.

Comment: I have a feeling Lacey's paper has been mentioned elsewhere on MO before, but I could be misremembering.

Comment: Thank you very much Yemon! The question is motivated by the work of Dales, Lau and Strauss, but I didn't know about the current state of the art.

Comment: @Bob the question rang a bell because Dales mentioned it to me in 2007 and I was unable to say anything intelligent then :)

Comment: To the best of my knowledge Dales *et al*. are going to publish (rather soon) a survey article on this and related problems. I will keep you posted.

Answer (score 5):

This is a detailed version of a previous comment that gives a partial answer. 
If $K$ is a compact space and $C(K)$ is isometrically isomorphic to $X^{**}$, then $X$ is a $\mathcal{L}_{\infty}$-space. Hence $X^{**}$ is injective.

It was proved by R. Haydon [Israel J. Math. 31 (1978), 142-152] that an injective bidual space is isomorphic to $\ell_\infty(\Gamma)$ for some set $\Gamma$. Hence $C(K)$ is isomorphic to $c_0(\Gamma)^{**}$.

I do not know if $C(K)$ is isometrically isomorphic to $c_0(\Gamma)^{**}$.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding something: but I think that if $C[0,1]^{**}$ were isometrically isomorphic to $c_0(\Gamma)^{**}$ then uniqueness of isometric preduals would imply that $M[0,1]=C[0,1]^*$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^1(\Gamma)$. But this is impossible since $M[0,1]$ contains a complemented copy of $L^1[0,1]$, while all  complemented subspaces of $\ell^1(\Gamma)$ are $\ell^1$ of something.

Comment: Yemon, Haydon in his proof uses Pełczyński's decomposition method hence his result is *only* isomorphic not isometric, so the trick with uniqueness of preduals doesn't work. This situation is analogous to the fact that there exists a Banach-space between apparently very different Banach algebras $\ell_\infty$ and $L_\infty$. I am not sure if the OP is happy with Banach-space isomorphisms, though.

Comment: @TomekKania I was responding to the last part of this post, giving a reason why $C(K)$ cannot be isometric to any $c_0(\Gamma)^{**}$ when $K$ is the max ideal space of $C([0,1])^{**}$. I had noticed the point you raise when looking at Haydon's proof.